# MySQL: Identical Values Not Identical

Tags: php, mysql

I read up on a similar question on here, but I'm not sure how to make it pertain to MySQL.

I've got a file of numbers I'm inserting into a table for record keeping. I'm reading the file, connecting to my database, and querying the database using PHP. Everything is working fine in that department, here's my code:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname; dbname=$database", $username, $password);

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
print "Connected to Database\n\n\n";

$file = "missing.txt";
$fileArray = preg_split("/[\t\r]/", file_get_contents($file));

for ($i = 0; $i < count($fileArray); $i++) {
    if ($i == 0 || $i % 7 == 0) {
        $sql = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO temp_missing SET SKU = ?;");

        $sql->bindParam(1, $fileArray[$i]);

        $sql->execute();
        echo $fileArray[$i] . "</br>";
    }
}
```

Now by all appearances, the data being sent to MySQL is fine. Row 1 contains a value 03999. I know this value exists in our other table, so I'll type a select command out to grab specific information from one table based on these numbers that exist in this new table.

```
SELECT num, name, description FROM table1 WHERE num IN (SELECT SKU FROM temp_missing);
```

This doesn't return anything. Not a thing. If I type out the following:

```
SELECT * FROM temp_missing WHERE SKU = 03999;
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE num = 03999;
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE num = '03999';
```

They all return something. They all return a row in which num or SKU is 03999. But the following returns nothing:

```
SELECT * FROM temp_missing WHERE SKU = '03999';
```

That returns nothing, and I can't seem to find anything on the internet (or at least I can't phrase my questions correctly) to figure out why they're not the same, and how to make them the same.

The following is how those two fields are set up:

**table1**

num -> VARCHAR -> Length/Set: 20 -> No unsigned, No Allow Null, No Zerofill, Default left blank, everything after left blank

**temp_missing**

SKU -> VARCHAR -> Length/Set: 50 -> No unsigned, No Allow Null, No Zerofill, no Default, everything after left blank

There is one big difference between the two I just noticed (I didn't create both of these tables, I've sort of picked up after previous programmers).

**num** is a KEY. **SKU** is nothing.

Does this make the difference??

Please let me know if this makes sense and if any more information is required, and if there happens to be a question to this I just couldn't find- believe me, I've been trying to go over this for months with different workarounds, I just couldn't find one this time- I do apologize.

Thank you.

**As an addendum,** the file I'm reading from- missing.txt- was created as a text-tab delimited from an excel file that was formatted to have entirely text formatted rows and columns. In case that makes a difference.

Comment: `03999`.... the leading zero in PHP means an octal number, except it's invalid octal because of the `9`s, so will translate as `03` or decimal `3`.... that could certainly cause problems

Comment: `INSERT INTO table SET`? Don't you mean `UPDATE table SET val WHERE ...` or just `INSERT INTO table (col) VALUES (?)`?

Comment: @MarkBaker so is there a way to work around that? I unfortunately can't get rid of the leading 0's.

Comment: The leading zero is not a problem as long as it's treated as a string - ie `'03999'` instead of `03999`. The column in the database is varchar anyway, so that's a string.

Comment: @Xorifelse Hmmm, I think you're right, that's how I originally did Inserts like a year ago, I don't know when I started writing it this way. They apparently do the same thing- I didn't notice until just now that I'd done that. Would it make a large difference?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie But the values still aren't the same. Somehow '03999' in table1 is not the same as 03999 in temp_missing.

Comment: I don't think leading zeros are a problem in PHP if they form part of the query.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the `temp_missing` table actually contain what you think it contains?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie No, and that's the part that's frustrating. This is what it APPEARS to show, but clearly it's not the same value.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie To add on to my previous response, I'm not sure how to make it 100% the same value. My above process has worked before with different files and information, but every now and then the values somehow aren't the same. I've tried checking for whitespace, invisible characters. I should mention the text file I'm reading from came from an excel file originally formatted to text tab delimited.

Comment: Could it be that `select * from temp_missing` returns values without the prepadded "0", so "3999" instead of "03999"? Try using `bindValue` instead of `bindParam`, and use the third argument:  `$sql->bindValue(1, $fileArray[$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);`. Also make sure that at no time you do something with `$fileArray` that could cause its values to convert to numbers instead of strings.

Comment: @trincot I'll give that a go and let you know!

Comment: @trincot I tried a multitude of things based off of your response, and I can honestly say this is incredibly bewildering. I tried bindValue, but that alone made no difference- it still doesn't recognize '03999' as 03999. So I tried changing the Datatype to Text, as a force-all to string. Still didn't recognize it. I tried removing the preg_split in the idea that it was converting my string to numbers, but that simply broke the program and didn't allocate to arrays correctly. I'll look into some other options apart from preg_split on the offchance that's it, but it's still not working

Comment: Do a `var_dump($fileArray)` just before the loop, and see what the data type is of the array elements. If it is not string, then there is your problem. `preg_split` returns an array of strings, but maybe you have some other code working on that array? Also, can you confirm what `select * from temp_missing` returns? Does it have the pre-padded zero in the reported SKU values?

Comment: @trincot Nope. Apart from setting my password and database information and then setting $dbh to null, what you see above is this entire script. I do a lot of file translations here, so I have this one as a template script that I modify depending on what needs to go to SQL or through SQL. *Also I will try the varDump, may have what I need!

Comment: I did not get what `select * from temp_missing` is returning...

Comment: @trincot This is the dumbest. Check this out: `string(8) "Item No." [1]=> string(6) " 03999" `. There's a space in front of 03999. I can absolutely swear up and down I've been checking for white space. Now I have to figure out how to get rid of it. And after a reason run it looks like SQL is interpreting that white space not as a space but as a return line. -.- ***Hang on though, that doesn't make any sense my preg_split is supposed to take care of that, argh.

Comment: Use this regex instead: `/\s*[\t\n]\s*/`: it will remove the spaces. Note that you had `\n` in your strings, since you split by `\r`, but newlines have most often `\n` in them, even when you have an encoding with `\r` present.

Comment: @trincot Thank you so much, that was exactly what I needed, I'll post an official answer to the question. I can't believe it was both as ridiculous as a Regex overlook and as blatant as whitespace. I'll have to make a larger effort to learn more about regex in the future, since i deal with file conversions so often.

Comment: @trincot I belatedly remembered answers can get reputation, did you want to post the answer instead so you can get the points?

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the mismatch is that your regular expression tests for `\r`, but not for `\n`. As your file probably has `\r\n` sequences for denoting line-breaks, you will end up with strings that start with `\n`. If also your lines have spaces adjacent to the tab delimiters, then also these will appear in your data.

In order to solve this, change your regular expression to this:

```
/\s*[\t\n]\s*/
```

The `\r` does not need to be mentioned explicitly as it will be covered by `\s`. The explicit mention of `\t` and `\n` is still required as otherwise you would also split by spaces that occur within single fields.

Alternatively, you could also remove white space around your values after the split, with this mapping:

```
$fileArray = array_map('trim', $fileArray);
```